# Equality type and Propositions

Tags: lean

I'm writing a library in the Lean computer proof assistant.

Evidently,

```
X : Type
x : X
y : X
#check x = y
```

Produces "Prop" and not "Type"; propositions are handled within the prop type. Unfortunately, I wanted to actually obtain the pullback of sets like so:

```
X : Type
Y : Type
Z : Type
f : X \rightarrow Z
g : Y \rightarrow Z
\Sigma (x : X), \Sigma (y : Y) , f(x) = g(y)
```

Since f(x) = g(y) produces a proposition instead of the singleton I'm at a loss to construct the pullback the way I'd like. Is there an alternative to the equality type in Lean which produces instead the singleton? It'd be nice to have a way of constructing maps Prop -> Type, particularly the one sending 1 to * and 0 to empty type.

Comment: Is

```def fiber_product {X Y Z} (f : X → Z) (g : Y → Z) : set (X × Y) := { x | f x.1 = g x.2 }```

what you had in mind?

Comment: Just a comment: before you go too far in Lean, note that Lean isn’t very good for doing purely constructive mathematics.  I don’t know your goals, but you be in for  a lot of pain if you need to say redefine equality.

Comment: [Section 7.7 of TPIL](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/inductive_types.html#inductive-families) has the definition of equality in Lean.  You should be able to make a Type valued version which would have the right eliminators.

Comment: Also if you are looking to redefine equality, check out https://github.com/gebner/hott3 which does this.

Comment: Do you mean **sub**-singleton instead of “singleton”? Also, what is the problem with `Prop`? Propositons are subsingletons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ways I believe you can define the pullback:

```
def pullback1 {X Y Z : Type*} (f : X → Z) (g : Y → Z) : Type* :=
  Σ' (x : X) (y : Y), f x = g y
def pullback2 {X Y Z : Type*} (f : X → Z) (g : Y → Z) : Type* := 
  { x : (X × Y) // f x.1 = g x.2 }
def pullback3 {X Y Z : Type*} (f : X → Z) (g : Y → Z) : Type* := 
  Σ (x : X) (y : Y), { u : unit // f x = g y }
def pullback4 {X Y Z : Type*} (f : X → Z) (g : Y → Z) : Type* := 
  Σ (x : X) (y : Y), plift (f x = g y)
```

I believe they are all isomorphic types (but likely not provably equal, since few types in Lean are provably equal unless they are definitionally so).

The first is using [`psigma`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/core.html#psigma) (`Σ'`) instead of [`sigma`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/core.html#sigma) (`Σ`) or [`Exists`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/logic.html#Exists) (`∃`).  `psigma` works with `Prop` unlike `sigma` and returns a `Type` unlike `Exists`.

The second uses [`subtype`s](https://leanprover-community.github.io/theories/sets.html#sets-and-subtypes).  In particular, the difference between damiano's suggestion of a fiber product using `{ x | f x.1 = g x.2 }` and this suggestion of a pullback using `{ x : (X × Y) // f x.1 = g x.2 }` is that the former is a subset and the later is a subtype.  A subset of `X` is an element of `set X` which is the same as `X -> Prop`.  But if you want to turn your set into a type, you use a subtype instead.  See [Section 7.3 of Theorem Proving in Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/inductive_types.html?highlight=subtype#inductively-defined-propositions).

The third is a bit of a hack to get you what you asked for, namely a way to turn a Prop into a Type.  The subtype `{u : unit // p}` is a Type which behaves like the prop `p`.  <strike>Of course, this is a hack that we likely never need, but if it was actually useful, one could define this directly, by modifying the definition of [`subtype`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/core.html#subtype) removing the `val` field.</strike>

**Edit:** The fourth way (just added) uses [`plift`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/logic.html#plift) which is the proper way to lift a `Prop` to a `Type`.

---

You asked for a way to turn a `Prop` into a `Type` such that `true` maps to `unit` and `false` maps to `empty`.  That is certainly possibly using [`classical.dec`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/logic/basic.html#classical.dec).  This uses the axiom of choice to show that every element of `Prop` is decidable and is therefore either true or false, and you can do a case split mapping one to `unit` and the other to `empty`.

But I doubt there is a nicer way to do that, mostly again since one can't prove isomorphic types are equal.  For example, I don't think the subtypes `{u : unit // true}` and `{u : unit // false}` are provably equal to `unit` and `empty` respectively.

---

In the comments above, I likely overreacted to the idea of you wanting to "redefine equality" in Lean. In some other set theories equality is a type, but it is build deeply into Lean that equality is a `Prop` and the equality proofs are unique.  This limits the ability to do homotopy type theory in Lean, or very pure constructive mathematics.  I see now you were just trying to get `sigma` to work with a `Prop`.

---

If you are interested, here is the definition of a [`pullback`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/category_theory/limits/shapes/pullbacks.html#category_theory.limits.pullback) in Lean.  You could use this to find the pullback that mathlib uses for the category of `Type`s and how they define it.

Comment: Thanks Jason this is very helpful.

Comment: @Topologic I just added another version using `plift` which is the proper way to lift a `Prop` to a `Type`.